# React re-renders entire function when state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-suspense

I'm look at implementing a loading screen that checks if all components are loaded, but came across this weird pattern. With the code below, I get `App false` in console to start, after 2000ms when the delayHTML function returns back data, I get `LoadComponent mount event` and `App true`.

But then it goes back into the suspense fallback, and I get a further 2000ms where the `LoadComponent mount event` and `App true` messages appear again, in what looks like a 2nd render. How can I avoid that?

```
function App() {
  const [fullLoadState, setfullLoadState] = useState(false);
  
  console.log("App " + fullLoadState)

  eventBus.on("FullyLoaded", (data) => setfullLoadState(true));

  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback='Fallback'>
        <LoadComponent resource={delayHTML(2000)}/>
      </Suspense>
      <p>{fullLoadState ? null : "Site not fully loaded" }</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function LoadComponent({resource}){
  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log ('LoadComponent mount event')
    eventBus.dispatch("FullyLoaded", {messsage: 'some message'});
  })
  const html = resource.read();
  return html;
}

export default App;
```

EventBus is just EventListener. delayHTML suspends until it reaches 2000ms to return a text value.

Comment: Both messages are expected behaviour. Changing state causes component (App) rerender. `useEffect` w/o dependencies also runs on every render.

Comment: Also you should never perform side-effects (like subscriptions) in render. Move this code to `useEffect` with proper clean-up function. `eventBus.on("FullyLoaded", (data) => setfullLoadState(true));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the way how react renders its component, you can create a variable, assign delayHTML and use that.

For example,

```
const delayFunc = delayHTML(2000);
...
<LoadComponent resource={delayFunc}/>
```

This should work.

Comment: Tried a variation of this - const delayFunc = useState(delayHTML(2000)). This somewhat worked - there's no longer a 2nd loading for the suspense fallback, but `LoadComponent mount event` was logged twice in console. There is also an warning in console: `Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`LoadComponent`)`

Comment: Can you share delayHtml function body?

Comment: I think Yury may be right - state changes causes React to trigger the render() function again. 
function delayHTML(ms) {
  return (wrapPromise(new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('abc')
    }, ms
    )
  })))
}

Comment: Yes, state changes cause React to trigger render method again. This is how React is designed.

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted but it doesn't show here. Any ideas on the warning message? It doesn't affect anything but might not be the React way to do things.

Comment: I actually don't understand why you use eventBus. You can pass handler as props, which is a more easy and smart way.

Comment: Also, add [] to useEffect func.

Comment: Yep removed event bus in the final implementation - it was just shorthand for dev. Still has that error message though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and change your useEffect to this:

```
  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log ('LoadComponent mount event')
    eventBus.dispatch("FullyLoaded", {messsage: 'some message'});
  }, [])
```

Comment: Tried this and seems like there's no difference

Comment: So you can try something else. Change your eventBus.on function to this --> 
eventBus.on("FullyLoaded", (data) => if(!fullLoadState) setfullLoadState(true));